# Error when calling LambdaInvoke in aws CDK stepfunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I am trying to create a stepfunction via AWS CDK. 
The stepfunctions should, among other things, call a lambda function.
I am using the lambdaInvoke task as described in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks/LambdaInvoke.html 
For the lambda_function parameter I am trying to use an existing Lambda by referencing its ARN using
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/Function.html#aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function.from_function_arn 
(i tried using from_function_attributes as well)

My cdk code looks like this

```
        lambda_name = sfn.Task(
            self, "Lambda Name",
            task=sfn_tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, "lambdaInvoke",lambda_function=lambda_.Function.from_function_arn(self,"import-lambda",function_arn="arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:accountnumber:function:LambdaName")),
            result_path="$.guid"
        )
```

I am trying to call an existing lambda. (the lambda itself is created and updated in a pipeline setup in the same CDK project, but in a different stack)

I also tried adding :%LATEST to LambdaName, and both give me the same error:
`jsii.errors.JSIIError: props.task.bind is not a function`

I made a support ticket for the issue, they ran into the same issue and referred me to here.
How do I invoke a lambda via cdk?

**Update:**

LambdaInvoke is not supposed to be imbedded in a task.

```
lambda_name = sfn_tasks.LambdaInvoke(
   self, "lambdaInvoke", 
   lambda_function=lambda_.Function.from_function_arn(self,"import-lambda",function_arn="arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:accountnumber:function:LambdaName")),
   result_path="$.guid"
)
```

Works